# Why am I getting 2 values stored when reading from a file using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to separate the distance (odd number sequence line, e.g. 100,15,79... etc) and speed (even number sequence).
**Note:** these numbers are on separate lines in a notepad.

Inside `speeds.txt`:

```
100
80
15
30
79
120
85
100
40
90
78
80
90
65
150
120
```

Code:

```
counter=1
speed=0
distance=0

f=open('speeds.txt','r')
for rec in f:   #for loop to go through each line in the file
    rec= rec.strip('\n')
    if counter % 2 ==0:
        speed = float(rec)
    else:
        distance= float(rec)
    print(distance)
    counter = counter + 1

f.close()
```

Comment: You always print  `distance`, never `speed`

Comment: Where are these values being "stored"?

Comment: @martineau I stored the values read from a file (line by line) to a variable either speed or distance; depending on what line they are on(odd or even). Then I was asked to print only the distance (odd number lines), which worked but i get duplicates, like the picture I attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you read distance for odd lines but print it for each line. So at even lines you just print stored value. Add indent before `print` and you get only one output for each distance:

```
...
    else:
        distance= float(rec)
        print(distance)
...
```

Comment: alright that fixed the problem, now there are no more duplicates.. Thanks you're a livesafer